# Excel 2 tables different items some same items have same id, compare value in the row. (power pivot)

Tags: excel, compare, powerpivot

I have two tables (and more coming) of items with each a unique id.
However, in table 1 (month 1) there might be 5 items.
In table 2 there might be 4 of the 5 previous ones (still the same id) and 1 other one.
and in table 3 there might be 2 left of those (also still the same id) and 8 new ones.

What i try to do is compare the values of those same ID's. Preferable looking at the latest table and only use those current ID's as the old ones that are no longer in the lists became irrelevant.

```
Table 1
+-----+--------+------------------+
| id  | name   | times sold total |
+-----+--------+------------------+
|  11 | banana |    100           |
|  23 | apple  |    0             |
|  66 | bread  |    80            |
+---+-+--------+------------------+
```

```
Table 2
+-----+--------+------------------+
| id  | name   | times sold total |
+-----+--------+------------------+
|  11 | banana |    192           |
|  23 | apple  |    0             |
|  71 | cookie |    30            |
+---+-+--------+------------=-----+
```

Actually the most relevant information I am trying to retrieve is....
which item is in the newest table that is ALSO in the first table and has not sold anything since the first table. (or not sold a lot).

I tried using power pivot in excel, but I just can not get it to work.
ID's always stay the same. all other columns can vary (also the name can change).

It seems very simple to do, but I just need someone to tell me the steps in power pivot.
Or maybe even another tool, as long as i reach my goal.
(I know i could paste every new column of "times sold total" next to the old table and compare with a formula, but the items are not always the same so i don't think i can easily copy paste it.

I hope i explained clear what I am trying to do.